# -i option not working for mv

Tags: mv

The man for the `mv` command says there's a `-i` option to prompt a y/n before the command is executed, but it's not working for me. Each time I use `mv -i`, the file is automatically renamed without issuing a prompt. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: What does the command `type mv` say?

Comment: It says: mv is hashed (/bin/mv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-i` states

```
-i, --interactive
          prompt before overwrite
```

Logically you are doing a "mv" where the file does not exist yet. It will only prompt if the file you are moving it to exists. Simple test:

```
rinzwind@discworld:~/test$ ls
rinzwind@discworld:~/test$ touch 1
rinzwind@discworld:~/test$ mv -i 1 2
rinzwind@discworld:~/test$ touch 1
rinzwind@discworld:~/test$ mv -i 1 2
mv: overwrite ‘2’? y
rinzwind@discworld:~/test$
```

Comment: That's it. I didn't realize that -i works only when there's the potential for content to be overwritten. I was using it simply to change the file's name.

Comment: @AlcuinArundel no problem. Please accept mine or heemayl answer if you feel it is answered sufficiently (they basically are the same. He needs to rep so don't decide this on the 2 minutes I was quicker ;) )

Comment: OK, I just accepted your answer (I'm still getting the hang of things here :)

Answer (score 4):

From the man page of `mv` ([`man mv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/mv.1.html)):

```
-i, --interactive
              prompt before overwrite
```

So, `mv -i` will show a prompt in case of overwriting a file. Here is an example:

Only `mv`:

```
$ touch foo.txt
$ touch ../bar.txt
$ mv ../bar.txt foo.txt  ##No prompt
$ ls
foo.txt
```

With `mv -i`:

```
$ touch foo.txt
$ touch ../bar.txt
$ mv -i ../bar.txt foo.txt 
mv: overwrite ‘foo.txt’? y  ##Prompt being shown
$ ls
foo.txt
```